# Why do rings appear in regular polygons with diagonals?

Tags: geometry, polygons

When looking at regular polygons with all the diagonals filled in, I saw that concentric rings seem to form. Why does this occur? It's not so obvious with small $n$, but for larger $n$ it becomes increasingly clear.

To show what I mean, I have included the images of some regular polygons (the $n$ used as examples were chosen because I like them, but the pattern shows up for the other $n$s as well).

[image: n=15]

[image: n=21]

[image: n=28]

[image: n=35]

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737) can help ?

Comment: In a circle of radius $r$, every chord of length $2s$ is tangent to the concentric circle of radius $\sqrt{r^2-s^2}$. Each such circle is the [envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the associated infinite family of chords. In a polygon (especially one with many vertices), the diagonals of a particular length have a common tangent circle, and are "visually dense enough" to make this circular envelope apparent.

Comment: @Blue I think your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Converting comment to answer, by request.]

In a circle of radius $r$, every chord of length $2s$ is tangent to the concentric circle of radius $\sqrt{r^2−s^2}$. Each such circle is the [envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the associated infinite family of chords.

In a polygon, the diagonals of a particular length have a common tangent circle; for a polygon with lots of vertices, the families of diagonals are "visually dense enough" to make their circular envelopes apparent.